# query doesnot process my date format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have been trying to convert this date `5-Jan-76` with sql in `Jan, 05 1976` and i tried following methods but they returned `null` kindly let me know what wrong with the following query?:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('5-Jan-76', '%M,%d %Y')
select DATE_FORMAT('5-Jan-76','%M,%d %Y')
```

Comment: Consider tagging your question. This helps locating it, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first approach was correct but you did not use the right [format specifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

> **`%b`** Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
>   **`%d`** Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
>   **`%e`** Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
>   **`%Y`** Year, numeric, four digits
>   **`%y`** Year, numeric (two digits)

Here is what you need to do:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('5-Jan-76', '%e-%b-%y'), '%b, %d %Y'); -- Jan, 05 1976
```

Comment: my query becomes in that case `SELECT DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '5-Jan-76',  '%e-%b-%y' ) ,  '%M,%d %Y' ) `